# How to maintain custom case statement column in DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Eg:
[image]

Need to create custom column 'Solution' which holds value of Important solution value when Normal Solution and Requested Solution is other
So basically case statement should hold value of one solution name among three

Note: There will be no case that Solution name will be there for 2 Solutions i.e., if Important Solution has value then other Normal Solution and Requested Solution value will be others and vice versa

Output:
[image]

Comment: Does it have to be DAX?  You can easily add a column in the query using M-Code with this logic.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, Could you provide that

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can add the column within the query itself.

- Create a ***List*** of the columns you are testing.
- Use `List.Transform` to replace "Other" with *null*
- Remove the nulls from the list
- Returning the remaining item.

*If **all** the items are *null* or contain "Other", the result will be an *Error**, *but if that is possible, easily checked for.*

**Custom Column dialog**
[image]

***M Code***
*replace `#"Previous Step"` with the obvious*

```
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Custom Solution", each List.RemoveNulls(
            List.Transform(
                {[Important Solution],[Normal Solution],[Requested Solution]},
                each if _<>"Other" then _ else null)
            ){0})
```